# How can I get a file's creation time in microseconds or milliseconds using Python?

Tags: python, file, time

Python's getctime() method returns the value only in seconds. Is there a more accurate way?

Comment: Note: it's not necessarily the creation time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: Thank you for you comment.
Yeah, I know the differences on Windows and *nix. :)

Answer (score 1):

The time is stored in the underlying filesystem.

Using ext2 as an example the ctime is stored as "32bit value representing the number of seconds since january 1st 1970, of when the inode was created" (http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#I-CTIME)

If it is not storing the exact time to a millisecond so it is not possible to read it